# Jinja: Concatenate '#' + variable in HTML attribute?

Tags: html, django, pug, jinja2

In a Django project, I'm using Jinja + pug. To assist with the elements I'm talking about, I've added four forward slashes above them in the code below:

```
each val in bottles
            tr
                th(scope="row")= index
                ...
                    div.text-center
                        ////
                        button.btn.btn-default.btn-xs(type="button", data-toggle="modal", data-target='#{{ val.name }}')
                            span.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus.text-primary
                        button.btn.btn-default.btn-xs(type="button", data-toggle="modal", data-target=".remove-bottles")
                            span.glyphicon.glyphicon-minus.text-primary
                //- Add Quantity Modal
                ////
                div.modal.fade(tabindex="-1" role="dialog")(id="{{val.name}}")
                ...
```

So basically the first `button` will trigger the modal `div`, but I need to set `data-target='#{{val.name}}'`. Doing this results in a syntax error, while adding a space (like so `data-target='# {{val.name}}'`), adds a space between the pound sign (`#`) and `{{val.name}}`, which means that the IDs don't match.

How can I concatenate `#` and `{{val.name}}` with a space between them?

Comment: Can you show the error traceback?

Comment: I'm not really getting a traceback, except for a message `invalid syntax (<string>, line1)` I suspect it's because the form is being included from another file.

Comment: I think the problem comes from elsewhere not with Flask or Jinja2. Where do you get the data target value in js. Please have look at there. And console.log with it. Check it's printed in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
data-target="#" + val['name'])
```